# What's wrong with my arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm trying to work through this challenge and can't figure it out.

Here is the challenge:

Use the built in filter method to filter over the jobs array of objects and return the object of the person with a job as a programmer. Make sure to use the arrow function in conjunction with the filter method.

Should not use the ES5 function declaration syntax in your final solution.

Should not use a for loop.

Should not have the function keyword anywhere in the solution.

Here is the provided array:

```
var jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
            {programmer: "Steve"},
            {designer: "Alicia"}];
```

Here is my code:

```
var solution = jobs.filter((programmer) => programmer === "Steve");
```

var solution is also provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function you are passing to `filter`, the parameter is an object (because `jobs` is an array of objects), not a string. `programmer` would be a property on that object.

Another problem is that your code is checking for a particular name (Steve) when you should be checking whether the object *has* a `programmer` property.

Lastly, remember that `filter` returns an *array*, so your solution would be the first element of that array.

This works:

```js
var jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
            {programmer: "Steve"},
            {designer: "Alicia"}];

var solution = jobs.filter((person) => person.programmer)[0];

console.log(solution);
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is passing the objects to its callback (the arrow function). You need to check if that object has a property named `programmer` using `hasOwnProperty`:

```js
var jobs = [{receptionist: "James"}, 
            {programmer: "Steve"},
            {programmer: "Another Steve"},
            {designer: "Alicia"}];

var result = jobs.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty("programmer"));

console.log(result);
```